# Spring MVC + Elastic Beanstalk | templates nested in directory not found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, resources, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Spring MVC app that works totally fine in local.
When I deploy it to Elastic Beanstalk though, I have seen that it can't find templates that aren't at the first level in resources/templates.

Here is my project structure:

```
|resources
|---------templates
|----------------- courses
|------------------------- template1
|------------------------- template2
|---------template3
```

Template 3 is retrieved just fine.
If i move template1 and template2 up one folder (so /resources/templates/template1) they too are retrieved just fine.

Why if deployed to Elastic Beanstalk the nested resources can't be found? How can I fix this in a clean and practical way?

Comment: What does "deployed on AWS" mean exactly? Deployed on EC2, Elastic Beanstalk, ECS, EKS, Lambda? There is nothing specific about AWS that could cause this issue, most likely there is something about the way you are packaging the app into a .jar file that is causing it.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I deployed it on Elastic Beanstalk and yes, I'm packing it in .jar file.

Comment: Any idea of what I could check?

Comment: I would start by opening the jar file to see if the resources are actually being packaged in it correctly. I would also try running the jar file locally to see if you can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. This was my controller

```
@GetMapping("/courses/template2")
public String getTemplate2(Model model) {
    return "/courses/template2";
}
```

For some reason, locally it worked but in order to make it work on Elastic Beanstalk I had to remove the slash before the folder name (so from */courses/template2* to *courses/template2*).